# C++ Linked list behavior

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list, stdlist

I have some C code, where in there are two linked lists(say A and B) and A is inserted at a particular position into B and A still has elements.

How do I simulate the same behavior effectively using the C++ STL? If I try splice, it makes the second one empty.

Thanks,
Gokul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the elements. Consider something like this:

```
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::inserter(b, b_iterator));
```

If you want the same nodes shared by two lists, this is simply not supported by `std::list` (STL containers always have exclusive ownership). You can avoid duplicating the elements by storing pointers in the list, or by using `boost::ptr_list`, which internally stores pointers but offers a nicer API.

Comment: Note that is is potentially slower than the other solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349098/2349119#2349119). See the comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/2551808#2551808 for why that is.

Answer (score 7):

Try insert:

```
B.insert( position, A.begin(), A.end() );
```

to insert copies of the elements of A in B before 'position'. A itself remains unchanged. See this [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00577.html#a26d74d3e123282a1858a7dba4f97978d)