# Add a vector to a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Appending a vector to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/c-appending-a-vector-to-a-vector)

Can I easily sum a vector to another vector? What I mean is, push_back a vector to another vector:

{1, 2, 3} + {4, 8} = {1, 2, 3, 4, 8};

Do I have to do this manually:

```
for (int i = 0; i < to_sum_vector.size(); i++) {
    first_vector.push_back(to_sum_vector.at(i));
}
```

Or is there a C++/STL way of doing it? Thank you!

Comment: Also of: [how to concat two stl vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/how-to-concat-two-stl-vectors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can. The STL way is using `insert`:

```
first_vector.insert(first_vector.end(), second_vector.begin(), second_vector.end());
```

This inserts `second_vector` into `first_vector` beginning at the end of `first_vector`.

Comment: You confused the order of the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
dst.insert(dst.end(), src.begin(), src.end() );
```

Comment: You confused the order of the arguments.