# appending one vector to another end AND sorting one vector

Tags: c++

I have some questions about vector ;

- How can I append one vector in another end in time efficient way ?
- How can I sort one vector over using STL feature if type of it is NODE ? ( for NODE, look below )

  ex

  ```
  struct NODE {

             char name;

             .... // other things

  };
  ```

Comment: Well that's two unrelated questions. One at a time please. (And for both: what have you tried/looked into, and what didn't work out?)

Comment: For your first question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/c-appending-a-vector-to-a-vector and for your second question see: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=366064

Comment: Have you tried searching [`std vector append`](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=std+vector+append), or [`std vector sort`](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=std+vector+sort)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [std::vector::insert()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) can be used to insert from anything which uses the iterator protocol
- [std::sort()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) sorts in ascending order and takes an optional comparison function (or anything with `operator()` on it) which takes elements `a` and `b` and should return true if `a < b`.

Answer (score 2):

To append one vector to another:

```
myVec.insert(myVec.end(), myVec2.begin(), myVec2.end());
// if your compiler supports C++11 you can do:
myVec.insert(end(myVec), begin(myVec2), end(myVec2));
```

To sort your vector:

```
vector<Node> myVec;
// add elements...
sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());
```

Node should define the < operator:

```
bool operator<(const Node & rhs, const Node & lhs){
    return rhs.name < lhs.name;
}
```