# C++: is there an 'endless' container with an 'add all' method?

Tags: c++, containers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Appending a vector to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/c-appending-a-vector-to-a-vector)

I'm looking for unlimited container (one that I add elements at run time as much as I need as long as I have enough space),such as 'vector' or 'linked list' that has a methos that accepts another container and copies its elements.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `std::copy` and a `back_inserter` iterator to insert a range of values into any variable-size standard container.

`std::vector` also has an insert overload that accepts a range.

See [Appending a vector to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/c-appending-a-vector-to-a-vector), the answers are actually usable for containers besides just vectors.

Answer (score 1):

`vector` supports this functionality, go through the constructors:

```
template <class InputIterator>
     vector ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, 
               const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

And:

```
std::vector<int> source;  
//populate source
std::vector<int> dest(source.begin(),source.end());
```

Comment: I think he wants to add into an existing container, not only at creation time.

Comment: but I dont want to create a new 'vector' every time I want to add elements. generally, I need to add to my vector, arrays..

Comment: @kakush sorry, misunderstood the question. Won't edit as you already have the answer from Ben, but will leave it up as it can still be useful.