# C++ insert vector of intgers (as member of struct) into vector of intgers

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I want to push two vectors of integers (`id1.a`, and `id2.a`) into vector of integer `newId` but I got error C2440: 'initializing'

```
 cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>' to 'int'
```

This my code:

```
struct Ss {
    std::vector<int> a;
    double b;
    double c;
};

// function
Ss getNewId(Ss id1, Ss id2) {
    Ss newSs = Ss();
    std::vector<int> newId = vector<int>();

    //newId.push_back(id1.a);
    //newId.insert(id1.a.begin(), id1.a.end());
    newId.emplace_back(id1.a.begin(), id1.a.end());
    newId.emplace_back(id2.a.begin(), id2.a.end());

    newSs.a = newId ;

    // some code...//

    return newSs;
```

Now, I did fix the error using:

```
std::copy(id1.a.begin(), id1.a.end(), std::inserter(newId, newId.end()));
std::copy(id2.a.begin(), id2.a.end(), std::inserter(newId, newId.end()));
```

but I really don't know why I can't push a vector inside vector using (`insert`, or `push_back`, etc), and I want to learn. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

Comment: this SO answer also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2551785/356440

Comment: `newId.insert(newId.end(),id1.a.begin(),id1.a.end());`