# How to take a vector of vectors contents into a single column vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of vectors and I want to take the contents of it into a single column vector. i.e.,

input: A = [[1 2] [3 4]]

output: v = [[1][2][3][4]] (column vector)

Is there a quick way of doing this in C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending a vector to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/appending-a-vector-to-a-vector)

Comment: @KillzoneKid I do not think that post will help me in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by single column vector? A regular `std::vector<int>` or a vector of vectors like `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` ending up having only one row / column?

Comment: `>>I do not think that post will help me in this case` This is exactly what you wanted and what you accepted as the answer, while in your ticket you described something different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I have to tell you, that every other answer, at least until now, is not as good as it seems.

Let us step through the answers; in the end I tell you how to handle it properly.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 3}};
std::vector<int> b;
for(auto& vec : v){
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(b)); // performes single insertion at the end
}
```

`std::copy` is bad style for inserting into a `std::vector`. You insert it value by value at the end of the destination vector. This means potentially more reallocations and moves/copies as needed.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv = { { 1, 2, 3 },
                                     { 4, 5, 6 },
                                     { 7, 8, 9 } };
std::vector<int> v;
for (auto row : vv) {
    for (auto el : row) {
        v.push_back(el);
    }
}
```

Same here. You resize it at every `push_back`, that is absolutely not necessary!

I recommend you the use of `std::vector::insert`. It performs some internal resizes by its own.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 3}};
std::vector<int> b;
for(auto& vec : v){
    b.insert(std::cend(b), std::cbegin(vec), std::cend(vec));
}
```

This solution performs a resize before any insertion occurs. This will result in the best possible performance.

Here some testcode. Try it by your own:

```
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(100'000'000, 5);
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<int> b;
    b.insert(std::cend(b), std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v));
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "insert durtion:\t" << (end - start).count() << std::endl;

    b = std::vector<int>();

    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::copy(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), std::back_inserter(b));
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "copy durtion:\t" << (end - start).count() << std::endl;

    b = std::vector<int>();

    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto el : v)
        b.push_back(el);
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "copy durtion:\t" << (end - start).count() << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

This produces in x64 release in this output:

```
insert durtion:         132388657
copy durtion:           844505239
push_back durtion:      866565409
```

In the end, you could of course `resize` the vector first and then start the copy, but I think that's the wrong way to deal with that, if in fact, the `std::vector` already offers us this solution.

Comment: single note: if you are already using `std::cend(b)`, you should also use `std::cbegin(vec)` and `std::cend(vec)`

Comment: @Fureeish You could. But then you are preventing the algorithm from moving the elements. But you are right, for this purpose the `std::cend/std::cbegin` is the better choice.

Comment: The elements won't ever be moved unless you use `std::move_iterator`, will they?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> b;
for ( auto& row : a )
{
   for ( auto item: row )
   {
      b.push_back(std::vector<int>{item});
   }
}
```

Comment: @KillzoneKid, I think the output is a vector of vectors where the inner vector consists of just one item.

Answer (score 1):

You could `std::copy` every row using `std::back_inserter` like so:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 3}};

    std::vector<int> b;

    for(auto& vec : v){
        std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(b));
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think the OP wants a `std::vector` for each item in `vec`. In other words, type of `b` is `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: When I try to print your vector b, I do not get anything.

Comment: What do you mean? How are you trying to print out that vector?

Comment: @RSahu You are right, this is not what he asked in the ticket. He asked for solution you provided. Hence I am upvoting yours.

Comment: @KillzoneKid, Only if we could always express in words what our mind thinks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy all the elements from a vector of vectors into a single vector then utilize the two loops:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv = { { 1, 2, 3 },
                                     { 4, 5, 6 },
                                     { 7, 8, 9 } };
std::vector<int> v;
for (auto row : vv) {
    for (auto el : row) {
        v.push_back(el);
    }
}
//print out the vector:
for (auto el : v) {
    std::cout << el << ' ';
}
```

or utilize the [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) function.

Comment: When I try to print v, I do not get anything for some reason.