# Appending Temporary Vectors in One Line

Tags: c++, c++17

My goal is to fill a vector `v` with `1,1,1,2,2,2` (the length of the sequence is variable) by appending together two temporary vectors. I know that [this is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/appending-a-vector-to-a-vector), however I was wondering if there is a one-liner solution.

Here is the code I tried that did not work.

```
    int length = 3;
    vector<int> v(length, 1);//fill three 1s.
    v.insert(v.end(), vector(length, 2));//to fill three 2s, failed.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << ", "; // I want 1 1 1 2 2 2
    }
```

[Appending a vector to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551775/appending-a-vector-to-a-vector)

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you please post a [Minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is your question: how can the answer from "Appending a vector to a vector" be done without creating a temporary `v2` variable?

Comment: @WhiZTiM, is `v.insert(v.end(), vector(3, 2));` a example? vector(3, 2) is the temporay vector.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83a2c62871b618c3

Comment: @WhiZTiM Perhaps the actual size and values are not known at compile-time?

Comment: @Zhang If the size is not known at compile time, you should emphasize it by using a *variable* as the size of your temporarily constructed vector. Like `vector(some_size, 2)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes, you are right. the count(3) is variable.

Comment: As a workaround you could implement your own `template<typename T> std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> const& first, std::vector<T> const& second)`, and use it like `v = v + vector<int>(size, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is an "out of the box" way to do what you want in C++, but you can create your own way of doing this in a one-liner with templates (as suggested by Some programmer dude
).

```
template<typename T> 
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> const& first, std::vector<T> const& second) {
    std::vector<T> new_vec;
    new_vec.insert(new_vec.end(), first.begin(), first.end() );
    new_vec.insert(new_vec.end(), second.begin(), second.end() );
    return new_vec;
}

int main()
{
    const int length = 3;
    std::vector<int> AB = std::vector<int>(length,1) + std::vector<int>(length,2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < AB.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << AB[i] << " ";  // 1 1 1 2 2 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second vector could be passed by constant reference. The first could also be passed by constant reference if a new vector is created (and memory preallocated with `reserve`) in the function.

Comment: With the current code, you could begin by just changing the second argument to `std::vector<T> const& second`.